# Is it okay to have triangles in your mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, topology

As you can see in the following picture, my model always has a single triangle left, no matter in what way I knife the faces:
[image]

However, I wondered if its better to achieve something like that (Dino splash screen example):
[image]

As you can see, there are sometimes 5 squares hitting one point.

I wonder if it's reasonable to have some triangles here and there or if it would be better to discard them all. If so, what's the best way to achieve a result as shown in the 2nd screenshot? I tried as much as I could but I always end up having another triangle.

Comment: Hi :). As moonboots said, triangles are often present even in hi-quality models. If they're not causing any artifacts, a small amount is perfectly fine :)

Comment: To answer this "_I wonder if it's reasonable to have some triangles here and there or if it would be better to discard them all._": There is no rule or obligation to always discard them all. Neither triangles nor n-gons. It always depends on the specific geometry and what you are about to do with it. Sometimes it can even be helpful not to have quads. I would recommend Josh Gambrell's Youtube channel, he does a lot of hard surface modeling and often has tips how to battle bad shading and also some videos about where non-quad topology is even preferable.

Comment: Note that adding a single level of subdivision, perhaps even applying it, will give you an all-quad mesh, if that is something that is important to you.  (This fact should also make it clear that all-quad is not the be-all, end-all of topology....)

Answer (score 5):

If it doesn't create any bad shading you can keep your triangle, but if you want a quad you can use this topology instead:

[image]